# split columns into single row per in/out record

Tags: sql-server

I would like to split the SwipeTime and SwipeDescription in the same row for the entry and exit of a door.

Currently this is what the tables look like:

```
userid || SwipeDescription  ||  EmployeeName   ||  SwipeTime    
178    || Output On By Door || Alexandra Perez || 2019-08-07 08:00:56.453   
178    || Output Off By Door|| Alexandra Perez || 2019-08-07 08:01:02.300
```

```
SELECT 
    u.userid 
    --,u.name
   ,et.name AS SwipeDescription
   ,CASE 
    WHEN scs.FullName is NULL THEN u.name
    WHEN scs.FullName is NOT NULL THEN 'C - ' + scs.FullName
    END AS EmployeeName
    ,e.LoggedTime AS SwipeTime
    ,d.name AS Door

FROM [Users] AS u
LEFT JOIN [Events] AS e ON e.RecordIndex1=u.UserID
LEFT JOIN [EventTypes] AS et on e.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
join [Doors] AS d ON e.RecordIndex2 = d.DoorID
LEFT join SecurityContractorSignIn as scs on scs.Badge = u.lastname and SignInTime > CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
WHERE LoggedTime > CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) and d.doorid in (32, 50, 42, 51, 33) 
ORDER BY u.name,e.LoggedTime ASC
```

I would like the data to look like this:

```
userid || SwipeDescriptionIn  ||    EmployeeName   ||  SwipeTimeIn  
178    || Output On By Door || Alexandra Perez || 2019-08-07 08:00:56.453 || Output Off By Door|| 2019-08-07 08:01:02.300
```

Comment: What happens when they swipe back in? Or swipe out multiple times?What't eh primary key on this table? Your sample data doesn't have all the tables we see listed in your code... these would be helpful in understanding its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WITH (NOLOCK)

SELECT Main.userid,
       Main.SwipeDescription,
       Main.EmployeeName,
       Main.SwipeTime
FROM
(
SELECT U.userid,
       U.SwipeDescription,
       U.EmployeeName,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),U.SwipeTime,121)+' || '
       +(SELECT SUB.SwipeDescription+' || '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),SUB.SwipeTime,121)
         FROM 
         (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.userid ORDER BY T.userID,U.SwipeTime) AS RowNum,
                T.SwipeDescription,
                T.UserID,
                T.SwipeTime
         FROM Users T 
         WHERE T.UserID=U.UserID)AS Sub
         WHERE Sub.RowNum>1 ) AS SwipeTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.userid ORDER BY U.SwipeTime DESC) AS RowNum      
FROM dbo.Users U WITH (NOLOCK)
) AS Main
WHERE Main.RowNum=1
```

Comment: Thank you, This put me on the right path to get the code I needed